# How can I use the legacy version in TreePlot in Mathematica 12.0 and later?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, packages, compatibility

In other places on StackExchange, I read:  "In versions 12.0, `TreePlot` is changed substantially, and the legacy `TreePlot` is available under the name `` GraphComputation`TreePlotLegacy ``".

How do I go from this to actually using the legacy package?

`` Needs["GraphComputation`TreePlotLegacy"] `` gives an error.

I have a beautiful `TreePlot` created 6-7 years ago. Doesn't work now.

Comment: What version are you currently using? This is helpful to us if you can include this information.

Comment: I edited the title, as it was misleading. The question is actually not about packages. This is a built-in function, not part of a package.

Comment: Before you start using `TreePlotLegacy`, check if `TreePlot[tree, PlotTheme -> "ClassicDiagram"]` works well enough for you (it may or it may not, depending on the specific features of TreePlot you used).

Comment: To Szabolics: Trying to understand. Is GraphComputation`TreePlotLegacy not to be considered part of package, just a different context in the built-in system?  Thanks for your comments so far, helping me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call it like:

```
GraphComputation`TreePlotLegacy[KaryTree[9, 2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Just tested. So easy. Thanks very much. Appreciated! Took me a bit to realize that TreePlot had been changed and old options wouldn't work. Could be documented a bit better. But now I can move forward.